# SQL query to calculate interval discount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have trouble understanding how I can solve this problem with a T-SQL query.
I have a price column and a volume column. In another table a have discounts at different levels of volume. So my discount table could have values as

```
(StartLevel, DiscountFactor)
(0, 1);
(25, 0.95);
(50, 0.90);
(100, 0.75)
```

What I want is to calculate a total price. If Volume is 35, I want it to multiply

```
Price x ((35-25) x 0.95 + (25-0) x 1)
```

If the volume is 200, it should be

```
Price x ((200-100) x 0.75 + (100-50) x .9+(50-25) x .95+(25) x 1)
```

Can anybody help me with a query that solves this?

Comment: And some sample data

Comment: I have not got any valid results yet. I was thinking of a cross apply approch with a SUM. But where I get stuck is when I come to split up the columne number into each level of discount.
MSSQL 2012 or 2014 is my version

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the sql version. If the version is mssql 2008, is there a solution to this that not include ´LEAD´

Answer (score 1):

This can help:

```
DECLARE @products TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      price MONEY ,
      volume INT
    )
DECLARE @discounts TABLE
    (
      id INT ,
      Level INT ,
      Factor MONEY
    )

INSERT  INTO @products
VALUES  ( 1, 10, 35 ),
        ( 2, 15, 200 )

INSERT  INTO @discounts
VALUES  ( 1, 0, 1 ),
        ( 2, 25, 0.95 ),
        ( 3, 50, 0.90 ),
        ( 4, 100, 0.75 )



SELECT  p.id, p.price * SUM(ca.m)
FROM    @products p
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    * ,
                                Factor * ( -Level + LEAD(Level) OVER ( PARTITION BY p.id ORDER BY Level, d ) ) AS m
                      FROM      ( SELECT    1 AS d ,
                                            Level ,
                                            Factor
                                  FROM      @discounts
                                  WHERE     Level < p.volume
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    2 AS d ,
                                            p.volume ,
                                            0
                                ) t
                    ) ca
GROUP BY p.id, p.price
```

Without grouping it returns:

```
id  price   volume  d   Level   Factor  m
1   10.00   35      1   0       1.00    25.00
1   10.00   35      1   25      0.95    9.50
1   10.00   35      2   35      0.00    NULL
2   15.00   200     1   0       1.00    25.00
2   15.00   200     1   25      0.95    23.75
2   15.00   200     1   50      0.90    45.00
2   15.00   200     1   100     0.75    75.00
2   15.00   200     2   200     0.00    NULL
```

Then just `group by` product and `sum` of `m` results in:

```
id  Total
1   345.00
2   2531.25
```

Answer (score 0):

For a given `Volume` and `Price` you can get the discount based on interval using `LEAD` which is available in SQL Server 2012+ onwards.

**Sample Data**

```
DECLARE @PriceTable TABLE(Volume INT,Price DECIMAL(9,2) )

DECLARE @Discount TABLE(StartLevel int, DiscountFactor DECIMAL(9,2))


INSERT INTO @PriceTable
VALUES(75, 20.5),
(150, 20),
(250, 20.5),
(0, 15);


INSERT INTO @Discount
VALUES(0, 1),
(25, 0.95),
(50, 0.90),
(100, 0.75);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT Volume,Price,FinalPrice
FROM @PriceTable P
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (MaxLevel >=StartLevel) THEN (MaxLevel-StartLevel) ELSE 0 END *DiscountFactor)*P.Price as FinalPrice
FROM 
(
SELECT CASE WHEN LEAD(StartLevel)OVER(ORDER BY StartLevel) < P.Volume THEN LEAD(StartLevel)OVER(ORDER BY StartLevel) ELSE P.Volume END MaxLevel,StartLevel, DiscountFactor
FROM @Discount
) IQ
)T
```

**Output**

```
Volume  Price   FinalPrice
75  20.50   1460.6250
150 20.00   2625.0000
250 20.50   4228.1250
0   15.00   0.0000
```